# (= 1/5 0.2) is false?

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

This is in both common lisp (clisp and sbcl) and scheme (guile). While these are true:

```
(= 1/2 0.5)
(= 1/4 0.25)
```

This turns out to be false:

```
(= 1/5 0.2)
```

I checked the hyperspec, it says that "=" should check for mathematical equivalency despite the types of the arguments. What the heck is going on?

Comment: It is possible that the binary representations are not equal, in which case you would want to check if they are approximately equal.

Comment: That's pretty common in most computer languages.  Unless you are using a data type with the right precision, the actual result of a calculation may not be what you think.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

Comment: @Darthtater Well yeah, but given the spec for "=", the binary representation or the data type shouldn't matter, as "=" is specified to check for mathematical equivalency despite differences in binary representations / data types. Its the job of the implementators to check that "=" works as the spec says, isn't it? though i do understand that it might be difficult if the floating point format does not provide the precision to check. the implementations should find a workaround, no?

Comment: What you're perhaps meaning to propose is to ban flonums outright, and exclusively use decimal floating-point numbers. That'd work but be much slower since no common processor natively supports them, so it all has to be implemented in software.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that 0.2 really is *not* equal to 1/5. Floating point numbers cannot represent 0.2 correctly, so the literal 0.2 is actually rounded to the nearest representable floating point number (0.200000001 or something like that). After this rounding occurs, the computer has no way of knowing that your number was originally 0.2 and not another nearby non-representable number (such as 0.20000000002).

As for the reason why 1/2 and 1/4 work its because floating point is a base 2 encoding and can accurately represent powers of two.

Comment: but isn't that going against the spec for "="? why not do a workaround? like, when encountering a "=", evaluate all floating point calculations in the arguments with BCD or right in their ascii representation. or even better, if encountering floating point arguments, evaluate all other arguements with floating point.

Comment: never mind, i don't think the second option would work. and i know what's wrong with the first. i just feel perplexed that while the standard says one thing, the implementations do something different. and i always though that lisps strove for mathematical correctness, given their use of rationals instead of floating point to represent fractions. this is kind of a downer.

Comment: @JanHlavacek you didn't try it did you? it doesn't work, it's still false. would be neat if it did though. oh god, it evaluates to 13421773/67108864. i can't believe this is right for lisp.

Comment: You must write your own approximately equal test with a certain tolerance.

Comment: My point was, it evaluates to `13421773/67108864`.  So it is not equal to 1/5.  Which is not surprising, since `0.2` really stands for a floating point representation of `0.2`, which is not 0.2.

Comment: What is interesting, in Maxima: `:lisp (= 1/5 0.2)` evaluates to `T`, but `:lisp (rational 0.2)` is `3602879701896397/18014398509481984`.

Answer (score 10):

please read [What every Computer Scientist should know about Floating Point Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

This actually depends on what is coerced to what. If you think about it, then rational is more precise, so it makes sense to coerce to rational for comparison, rather then to float, however, if you consciously want to compare numbers as being floats you can force it by doing something like below:

```
(declaim (inline float=))
(defun float= (a b)
  (= (coerce a 'float) (coerce b 'float)))
(float= 0.2 1/5) ; T
```

Actually... there's more to it, since floats provide you with things like not-a-number, positive-infinity and negative-infinity. Infinities, for example, for the 64-bit floats are 10e200 iirc, so, there's nothing stopping you from creating a rational larger then infinity (or smaller then negative infinity!), so, perhaps, if you want to be super precise, you'd need to consider those cases too. Likewise a comparison to not-a-number must always give you nil...

Answer (score 1):

However, in scheme you have exact numbers, so you may ask (note the #e prefix, which means the number which follows is to be treated exactly):

```
> (= 1/5 #e0.2)
#t
```

Comment: That is implementation-dependent, BTW.  Some implementations implement `#e0.2` as the read-time equivalent of `(inexact->exact 0.2)`.